# AKKA: Failed to define Actor with a custom mail box configuration

Tags: java, akka

I am new to akka and tried to do the following simple example:

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Config cf = ConfigFactory.parseString(" bounded-mailbox {\n"
            + "  mailbox-type = \"akka.dispatch.NonBlockingBoundedMailbox\"\n"
            + "  mailbox-capacity = 1000\n"
            + "}");
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem", cf); ActorRef                  
        myActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class).withMailbox("bounded-mailbox"), "myactor");
        for(int index = 0; index<=100; index++) {
            myActor.tell(index, myActor.noSender());
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(120000);
        }catch (Exception exc){}
   }
```

MyActor.class - is a simple actor class to print the received messages.

I get following errors when I run this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate MailboxType [akka.dispatch.NonBlockingBoundedMailbox], defined in [bounded-mailbox], make sure it has a public constructor with [akka.actor.ActorSystem.Settings, com.typesafe.config.Config] parameters
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Mailboxes.scala:197)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Mailboxes.scala:195)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookupConfigurator(Mailboxes.scala:195)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookup(Mailboxes.scala:78)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.getMailboxType(Mailboxes.scala:154)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:717)
    ... 10 more
```

any thoughts?? I am running with akka-actor_2.10-2.3.7

Comment: Could you describe your problem a bit more before your initial block of code? It helps answer-ers know what the issue is rather than searching for it in the code. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to create an actor backed by a bounded non-blocking queue based mail box. This actor may get lot of messages so I do not want to have default mailbox which is unbounded. it is fine if I loose some messages when actor does not process messages fast. thanks

Comment: I tested with akka 2.4.3 and scala 2.11 and it works.

Comment: It's working with akka-actor_2.11-2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

```
mailbox-type = \"akka.dispatch.NonBlockingBoundedMailbox\"\n"
```

I think you script should change to

```
mailbox-type = "your.package.name.the mailbox'class  name"
```